# Factorize $8x^3 + 12x^2 -2x -3$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

How do I factorize this - 
$$8x^3 + 12x^2 -2x -3$$
I tried splitting the middle term but that didn't work , I tried factor theorem with various factors but even that didn't work. What can I do to factorize this? I need 3 factors.

Comment: Hint: Observe that the ratio of 8 to 12 is the same as the ratio of -2 to -3.

Comment: @Théophile How would you suggest I go about factorizing such questions? What should be my first steps?

Comment: A very good way to go about such questions is the rational root theorem, described below by Henry. If you happen to notice, however, the ratio that I mentioned, then proceed as follows: $8x^3+12x^2-2x-3 = 4x^2(2x+3) - 1(2x+3) = (4x^2-1)(2x+3) = \ldots$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to note the $8x^3$ and $3$ at each end and then, thinking of the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), see if any of $x=\pm3,\pm1,\pm\frac32,\pm\frac12,\pm\frac34,\pm\frac14,\pm\frac38,\pm\frac18$ make your expression zero.

Three of them do in this case, namely $x=-\frac32,+\frac12 \text{ and } -\frac12$, which gives you the complete factorisation in this particular example of $(2x+3)(2x-1)(2x+1)$, but even if you only noticed one then you could make a start.

This only works when there is a rational factor.

Comment: Thanks for explaining ! I would suggest you edit the answer to include the complete answer as some might object that you didn't really answer the question.

Comment: @Mayank: try that edit

Answer (score 9):

Hint: $8x^3+12x^2 = 4x^2(2x+3)$

Comment: Thanks! How would you suggest I go about factorizing such questions? What should be my first steps?

Comment: Practice. A lot. Until patterns like this start to stand out. Sometimes plotting the curve on a graphing calculator might help guess the factorization ($a$ is a root if and only if $(x-a)$ is a factor)